# form data not getting passed

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I'm practicing form validation with JavaScript but when I try to retrieve the data from the page it submits to I can't get it.

**form.html**

```
<body>
    Hello.<br />
    <form onsubmit="return validate()" action="process.php" method="POST">
    Enter name: <input type="text" id="name" /><br />
    Enter phone number: <input type="text" id="number" /><br />
    Enter password: <input type="password" id="paswd" /><br />
    Is there anything else you would like to add: <input type="text" id="anything" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Check Form" />
    </form>
</body>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
echo 'Here: '.$_POST['number']
?>
```

Whatever index I use I get " Undefined index: line 2". What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: So I can't use the `id` attribute I need the `name`? Is there anyway to prevent coding redundancy since the value of all `name`s will be the same as the corresponding `id`?

Comment: I think you missed some code when posting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `name` attribute in your fields

```
<input type="text" id="number" name="number" />
```

`$_POST` looks for the `name` attribute in the field to capture the field values and not `id`

Comment: That's strange. Try removing 'onsubmit' from the form tag and try again.

Comment: I lied when I said I had tried that. I had forgotten to refresh the page :(

Comment: No. You can just use `name` without the `id`

Comment: Doesn't JavaScript only use `id`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14430/discussion-between-celeritas-and-asprin)

Comment: For validation to happen, you need `id`  too since JS targets an element based on its `id`. So having both is good

Comment: @aspirin This is not true! the form DOM node has an `elements` property which keys are the `name`'s of any form element inside it.

Comment: @TorstenWalter Thanks. Didn't know that, I usually go for jQuery rather than JS

Answer (score 4):

Your inputs need the name of the element.

Such as:

```
<input type="text" id="number" name="number" />
```

The Php gets the form data looking these names, not the ids.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot `name` of input:

```
<input type="text" id="number" name="number" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your form elements names.

```
<input type="password" id="paswd" name="paswd" />
```

Interestingly names and ids share the same namespace. If you don't really need the ids, leave them be. Inside a validate function you can always access all elements with the `elements` object of the form.

```
// called onsubmit
var validate = function(e) {
    if (this.elements["paswd"].value.length < 4) {
        alert("password needs to have at least 4 characters");
        return false;
    }
    return true
};
```

I usually append the input type to my ids to differentiate them from field names

```
<label for="paswd-txt">Password: </label>
<input type="text" name="paswd" id="paswd-txt" />

<label for="save-cb">Remember me: </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="save" id="save-cb" value="1"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

So like  Vitor Braga said your inputs need the name of the element, but you only need this if you are using PHP to hadle the values of form in the submit, if you are using javascript to validaate like you said your were praticing you can obtain the value like this:

document.getElementById("number").value

Comment: but still is there no way around having both name and id? Yes I do use both JS and PHP.